# In Thunderbird - the "sent" folder is empty (in the Thunderbird app itself, not on the hard drive)

Tags: email, thunderbird, smtp

I'm not sure if this is the right StackExchange community, but I can't find any better.

In Thunderbird, we have folders on the left. And on any given account we have "Inbox", "Drafts", "Sent".

Everything works fine with the "Inbox" and "Drafts" folders, but the "Sent" folder is always empty, it is even grayed out, like it was not only empty but somehow inactive.

When I log in to my webmail, I can see the sent messages.

When I look into the "/home/konrad/.thunderbird/s3zrpwq3.default/Mail/Local Folders"  directory (which is supposed to be my default profile directory) there are only "trash" and "unsent messages". I'm not sure if there should be something else or not.

I've been trying to solve this for many many hours, to no avail.

Can somebody help me please? I think it's something about configuration, but I'm really lost.

System: KUbuntu 16.x 64 bits.

Comment: Is the Sent folder correctly mapped to the right place? Check Account Settings -> Copies and Folder -> Top section of panel, ensure that folder chosen for use as local Sent matches the one on the server. Also check folder properties to ensure that Tbird is looking for new mail in the folder.

Comment: Thanks, @dr.nixon - but when I go there, I can see "When sending messages, automatically:" and a few options, right now I changed that to "Other -> Local Folders -> Send" Now - when I sent a message, nothing appeared in the folder in Thunderbird, but, a new file appeared on the disk, in /home/konrad/.thunderbird/s3zrpwq3.default/Mail/Local Folders - "Sent.msf" as well as "Sent" (with no extension), and I can see the message I sent out there, still however, the "Sent" folder in Thunderbird is empty.

Comment: @dr.nixon - I think I nailed it down to this: if in Edit->Account Settings->Copies & Folders->Place a copy in: I set "Other -> Local Folders -> Sent," then the messages indeed appear in this folder, i.e. (on the left panel) - Local Folders/sent - but I really would like to see them in the "my_account_name/sent", i.e. where the "Inbox is" and "Drafts" etc. How do I do that?
Update: In the my_account/sent folder properties I can see "imap://konrad...@myEmailProvider.pl/Sent" - is that correct?

Comment: @dr.nixon : thanks for trying to help, it seems I can't give a thumbs up, due to my low reputation. But, to let you know, the solution was to **subscribe** to the right imap folder, like described here: http://www.pcworld.com/article/250202/thunderbird_tip_change_imap_folder_subscriptions.html - well, my provider decided to not call the folder "Sent" but they translated it to Polish (it's a Polish service provider) so TB did not know where to look for the "Sent" messages. Thanks again for trying!